# Ruby 'uuid'.strip NoMethodError (undefined method `strip' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby, uuid, pdflatex

I am getting this error: NoMethodError (undefined method `strip' for nil:NilClass)
When I call:

```
`uuidgen`.strip
```

As I known it should generate an UUID. I would make different, but Rtex uses this to generate the pdf files and I can't change the code. So I think it must be something in my project configuration.
Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found here: http://ruby.11.x6.nabble.com/Generating-a-unique-id-td2401970.html
The command between `` means that this is a shell command, then I tryed to execute in prompt: uuidgen and the SO did not recognize the command. After install Microsoft SDK, add uuidgen to the path and restart the enviroment, the command starts to works. I thing uuidgen is not native in Windows anymore.